# How to override new and delete for std::function without overriding it globally

Tags: c++, memory-management, embedded, new-operator, delete-operator

I am programming for embedded environments. I can't use the standard new and delete because they are not deterministic and can lead to heap fragmentation and eventual device run time failure.

I was using `std:function<>` until I found out that deep inside the stdlib definition there was this line of code that was getting executed:

```
{ __functor._M_access<_Functor*>() = new _Functor(std::move(__f)); }
```

Now I have two different **new** implementations used by the application, both allowed in terms of the embedded standards I am using .

1.) Globally overridden **new** allocates from a chunk of memory and throws an error on delete. Used for most objects that would otherwise be allocated statically.

2.) Class specific **new** that allocates from a pool of fixed sized blocks. It never leads to fragmentation, is fully deterministic  and has a O(1) bounded new and delete time.

If I want to use std::function, I need to override the **new** for the `std::function<>` without overriding it globally. I already have a different global new implementation (1) which would not be compatible with the intended usage. That is in fact how I picked up the problem.

Normally I would define a class  specific new and delete:

```
 class Context : public NetworkPacketContext {

      .......

      inline void* operator new(const size_t size) {
        return memory::allocateSmallBlock(size);
      }

      inline void operator delete(void* ptr) {
        return memory::freeSmallBlock(ptr);
      }

      .....
  };
```

But that would require changing the code for the standard library to insert class specific allocators and its a template implementation so I am not sure exactly how many memory pools I would end up with.

Any recommendations on how to do this.

Comment: `std::function` used to have allocator aware constructors. But it was poorly specified and implemented, and as a result removed in C++17. Good question, but I think that answer is you shouldn't be using `std::function`

Comment: Does this help: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/uses_allocator

Comment: So how does one store lambdas for calling later if you cant use std:function ?

Comment: Without `std::function` templates are your option. Whole standard library uses tamplates instead of `std::function` as they are more light.

Comment: Wouldn't you rather be productive and design the functionality of your application instead? This problem should make a big fat warning sign pop up in your head: I'm doing meta programming instead of real-world programming. There is only one solution: don't use all of the bloated meta programming features of C++. To begin with, some 80% of the standard libraries are a no-go in embedded systems.

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you if you posted a [MCVE]. Just implement `memory` in terms of `operator new` and `operator delete`'.  Clearly show where you need something like `std::function<>`.

Comment: I am thinking that lambdas, templates, and placement-new might figure in the answer, but it is not at all clear to me what the question is. :-)

Comment: Lundin this is used as a "Future" for work that takes a while to complete due to latencies etc. Generally lambdas work well for event driver environments and allow decoupling of the different  software layers very nicely. Generally there are other traditional options like defining call back interfaces etc.  But lambdas tend to generate less code and decouple better.

Comment: Now much of the standard library can't be used, not because it is 'bloated meta programming' but rather because it uses dynamic allocation that is not easily overridden in a meaningful way for embedded environments. That said if you can use the std:library,  its a win in both not having to roll your own, easier review and quite frankly often more efficient implementation. Because the current compiler optimisation of templates there is very little overhead for use of the std::library.  Anyway embedded normally has much more flash then RAM at least for the 32bit Cortex Socs I am currently using.

Comment: boost.function was allocator-aware before it was mangled by C++ standardization (unfortunately, boost back-ported the standard version in 1.36). You could fork/copy its 1.35 version. Or just use templates.

Comment: Cubbi - Looked at boost V1.35 but as far as I can tell its from before Cx11 and does not have conversions to deal with lambda type expressions. Boost is efficient but its template meta programming implementation is very difficult to understand and change and remove the dependencies to make a standalone include.